# Find and replace characters between " and "

Tags: replace, notepad++

I need to replace all the recurrences between `" "`

i.e.: this is the actual strings

```
"vis": "<aaaaaaaaaaaa>" ( a could be letter or number or <,>,| )
```

I want to replace all the recurrences like this

```
"vis": "1"
```

Is it possible with Notepad++ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `:\h+"\K[^"]+`
- Replace with: `1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
:\h+"       # colon, horizontal spaces, double quote
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
[^"]+       # 1 or more any character that is not double quote
                you may use [a-zA-Z0-0<>|]+ if you want to be more restrictive
```